# How to install Teamviewer as service while I'm connected as QS?

Tags: teamviewer

I need to install Teamviewer full package with automatic startup while I'm connected with TeamviewerQS, is it possibile?

Currently I have to download AnyDesk, close TeamviewerQS, install Teamviewer Full... it makes no sense.

Comment: The limitations your running into are likely connected to the abundance of abuse by scammers using TeamviewerQS to defraud individuals out of thousands of dollars. If these machines are connected to a domain I suggest remotely installing TeamViewer using appropriate AD management tools.

Comment: This ^^^ If you have time I suggest watching Jim Browning's videos at Youtube to understand the scope of what @Ramhound commented above. Very entertaining. The situation is so dire that Teamviewer even blocked connections from an entire country, the one that recently changed its name. Scammers are now using Anydesk.

Comment: As a TeamViewer subscriber, there might be more options you will have access to, but I don’t have access to those options. TeamviewerQS exists for a specific purpose. It’s not designed to remotely manage your own computer equipment. It’s to provide legitimate remote support services

Comment: I think we are a bit out of topic, I have to give remote support to my customer. I need to reboot the customer's computer while it is unattended, the only way I image is to install TV as service. This is the root reason of the question.
I could solve using AnyDesk while installing TV, but it sounds strange to me.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I saw that video and it is great. However, I'm not a BT Techincian :-) and my customers well knows me and when I need to connect their pc, all my support sessions starts from a request from the customer to the customer care phone nr